# Make NLog log even when testing with UnitTests c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nlog, xunit

As the title says, I want my Logger to not be ignored when running unit tests using XUnit.  I want it still to log.  If this is possible, how can it be done?

***Here is my config***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="log"
       xsi:type="File"
       fileName="${basedir}/logs/log.${longdate:cached=true}.log"
       layout="${message}"
       archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/log.${shortdate}.{#}.log"
       archiveAboveSize="5242880"
       archiveEvery="Day"
       archiveNumbering = "Rolling"
       maxArchiveFiles="20"
     />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="trace" writeTo="log" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I just have a backend and no frontend, so when I run the tests I want to see that everything logs :)

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: XUnit I think it's named

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476927/nlog-and-unit-testing) help?  I don't know XUnit well enough to judge.

Comment: Hi! I've read the solutions on that question, but it does not help me.
On the other hand I don't really understand the solutions, doesn't seem like any real suggestions on that part

Also I don't get any errors, the console doesn't even open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock the logger of NLog and read logged message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004805/mock-the-logger-of-nlog-and-read-logged-message)

Answer (score 2):

You could use NLog in unit tests. Unfortunately it's difficult for NLog to find the path to the nlog.config as unit test frameworks move the binaries between folders - and not the nlog.config.

Also it's different in different environments/frameworks (NUnit, xUnit, MSTest, .NET full, .NET Core)

You could do:

- Write the configuration in C#. See [Docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API)
- Or tell NLog the path to the config:

  ```
  LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("pathToNLogConfig/nlog.config");
  ```

Also recommend for logging in unit tests, write to the memory target instead of file/database etc. You could also retrieve in code the logged events. See [memory target docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Memory-target)

Comment: NLog static nature doesn't work well with xUnit parallel test execution. Unless wanting to disable the parallel test execution. Then you need to create isolated NLog LogFactory and perform dependency-injection. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging

Comment: I have logs in the real projekt. 
I just want the XUnit to not ignore them :P 
I get Errors when i add that to the code @Julian

Comment: "Not ignore" is a bit ambiguous here. Do you like to assert the logs in NLog? "I get Errors when i", is that good or isn't? A bit unclear without an actual error message ;)