# Mock the logger of NLog and read logged message

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, moq, nlog

Im using NLog 4.5.11 for logging and moq 4.10.1 for mocking.

I have a middleware which writes exception details to the log file using NLog.

I need to unit test middleware in my API project and check the logged message for proper values.

This is how i have declared exception logger :

```
private static Logger _exceptionLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("ExceptionLogger");
```

This is how im initializing Logmanager in middlewares constructor :

```
 LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
```

and this is how im logging the exception message :

```
_exceptionLogger.Error(exceptionMessage);
```

Is there any way we can do this without actually writing and reading logged message in a file ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a custom target (this is an easy task) from which you can read what was logged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of mocking the logger, it's recommend to use the [Memory target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Memory-target) in unit tests.

For example:

```
// Arrange
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
var memoryTarget = new NLog.Targets.MemoryTarget();
memoryTarget.Layout = "${message}";   // Message format
config.AddRuleForAllLevels(memoryTarget);
LogManager.Configuration = config;

// Act
// Your call

// Assert
var logEvents = target.Logs;
// E.g. contains message in logEvents
```

PS: Please note that in the example above the global LogManager is used, so you can't run the tests in parallel. If you need tests in parallel, create a new [LogFactory](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/T_NLog_LogFactory.htm) and pass the LogFactory or created logger to your class / method.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here and looking for an answer for NLog 3.2.x solution is very similar:

```
// Arrange
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
var memoryTarget = new NLog.Targets.MemoryTarget();
config.AddTarget("mem", memoryTarget);

// Adjust the log level as needed
config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Warn, memoryTarget));
LogManager.Configuration = config;

// Act

// Assert
var logs = memoryTarget.Logs;
```

Hope it helps